# Finding the distribution of a vector of random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

I've encountered this question:

Let (X,Y) be a jointly distributed normal vector. Find the distribution of

(X, E(X|Y))
assuming Cov(X,Y) isn't singular.

I'm unsure what to do - I tried using the joint MGF to perhaps understand the new distributions parameters but am failing. would appreciate pointers, thanks!

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3736621/321264). Decide where you want to ask.